# Linq: Exclude results using Zip

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of bool, and a list of strings.  I want to use IEnumerable.Zip to combine the lists, so if the value at each index of the first list is true, the result contains the corresponding item from the second list.

In other words:

```
 List<bool> listA = {true, false, true, false};
 List<string> listB = {"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"};
 IEnumerable<string> result = listA.Zip(listB, [something]); 
 //result contains "alpha", "gamma"
```

The simplest solution I could come up with is:

```
 listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => a ? b : null).Where(a => a != null);
```

...but I suspect there's a simpler way to do this.  Is there?

Comment: I curate SharpExtensions (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpExtensions) which has an extension method for this (IncludeIf<T>/IncludeIf<TSource, TArgs>) and many many other extension methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is simpler:

```
listA
 .Zip(listB, (a, b) => new { a, b } )
 .Where(pair => pair.a)
 .Select(pair => pair.b);
```

That logically separates the steps. First, combine the lists. Next, filter. No funky conditionals, just read it top to bottom and immediately get it.

You can even name it properly:

```
listA
 .Zip(listB, (shouldIncludeValue, value) => new { shouldIncludeValue, value } )
 .Where(pair => pair.shouldIncludeValue)
 .Select(pair => pair.value);
```

I love self-documenting, obvious code.

Answer (score 4):

This is as short as I could get it:

```
var items = listB.Where((item, index) => listA[index]);
```

`Where` has an overload that provides the index. You can use that to pull the corresponding item in the bool list.

Comment: I hate funky index magic. This is short, but I have to mentally parse it.

Comment: @usr I tend to agree, although with proper naming and used in appropriate, simple contexts (like above) I think it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

```
listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => new { a, b }).Where(x => x.a).Select(x => x.b);
```

It uses anonymous type to handle `Zip` method subresults.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Zip` if you can index into `listA`:

```
var res = listB.Where((a, idx) => listA[idx]);
```

Comment: Yes, it will work. As long as `listA` is really a list, not `IEnumerable<T>`.